# Hodge self-duality in Minkowski spacetime

Tags: hodge-theory, semi-riemannian-geometry

I was computing the dual map for $k$-forms in Minkowski spacetime, and I found that any $2$-form is either self-dual or anti-self-dual if and only if it is the null form. Does this result make any sense to you? Here are the calculations.

Let the metric on Minkowski spacetime be

$$
(\eta_{\mu\nu})=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&-1&0&0\\
0&0&-1&0\\
0&0&0&-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and let $\omega$ be the $2$-form

$$
\omega=\omega_{\mu\nu}\ dx^{\mu}\wedge dx^{\nu}=(\omega_{\mu\nu}-\omega_{\nu\mu})\ dx^{\mu}\otimes dx^{\nu}
$$

The $\eta$-raised components of $\omega$ are

$$
(\omega)^{\mu\nu}=\eta^{\mu\lambda}\eta^{\nu\tau}\,(\omega_{\lambda\tau}-\omega_{\tau\lambda})
$$

We have

$$
\eta^{\mu\lambda}\eta^{\nu\tau}\omega_{\lambda\tau}=(\eta\omega\eta)^{\mu\nu}
$$

Thus, if

$$
\omega_{\lambda\tau}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&\omega_{01}&\omega_{02}&\omega_{03}\\
\omega_{10}&0&\omega_{12}&\omega_{13}\\
\omega_{20}&\omega_{21}&0&\omega_{23}\\
\omega_{30}&\omega_{31}&\omega_{32}&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$\eta\omega\eta$ has components

$$
(\eta\omega\eta)^{\mu\nu}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&-\omega_{01}&-\omega_{02}&-\omega_{03}\\
-\omega_{10}&0&\omega_{12}&\omega_{13}\\
-\omega_{20}&\omega_{21}&0&\omega_{23}\\
-\omega_{30}&\omega_{31}&\omega_{32}&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The $\eta$-raised components of $\omega$ are thus

$$
(\omega)^{\mu\nu}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&\omega_{10}-\omega_{01}&\omega_{20}-\omega_{02}&\omega_{30}-\omega_{03}\\
\omega_{10}-\omega_{10}&0&\omega_{12}-\omega_{21}&\omega_{13}-\omega_{31}\\
\omega_{20}-\omega_{20}&\omega_{21}-\omega_{12}&0&\omega_{23}-\omega_{32}\\
\omega_{30}-\omega_{30}&\omega_{31}-\omega_{13}&\omega_{32}-\omega_{23}&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Let $*\,\omega$ denote the Hodge-dual of $\omega$, such that (as $\sqrt{|\det(\eta)|}=1$)

$$
(*\,\omega)_{\tau\lambda}=\frac{1}{2}\ (\omega)^{\mu\nu}\,\epsilon_{\mu\nu\tau\lambda}
$$

Then, for example

$$
(*\,\omega)_{01}=\frac{1}{2}\ (\omega)^{\mu\nu}\,\epsilon_{\mu\nu 01}=\frac{1}{2}\,(\omega^{23}-\omega^{32})=\omega_{23}-\omega_{32}
$$
and

$$
(*\,\omega)_{23}=\frac{1}{2}\ (\omega)^{\mu\nu}\,\epsilon_{\mu\nu 23}=\frac{1}{2}\,(\omega^{01}-\omega^{10})=\omega_{10}-\omega_{01}
$$
Thus

$$
\begin{cases}
(*\,\omega)_{23}=(\omega)_{23}\\
\\
(*\,\omega)_{01}=(\omega)_{01}
\end{cases}
$$
implies

$$
\begin{cases}
\omega_{01}=\omega_{10}\\
\\
\omega_{23}=\omega_{32}
\end{cases}
$$
and the same goes for the other indices. The result is the same provided that

$$
\begin{cases}
(*\,\omega)_{23}=-(\omega)_{23}\\
\\
(*\,\omega)_{01}=-(\omega)_{01}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I think you mean $(\star \omega)_{23} = \omega_{10}$?

Comment: Where, exactly?

Comment: Nevermind. By "null form" you mean the zero 2-form?

Comment: Yes, I mean the zero 2-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is so. A simpler way to see this is to use clifford algebra.  Suppose $\omega$ is (anti-)self-dual. Then the clifford product of $\omega$ and the unit pseudoscalar $\epsilon$ is

$$\epsilon \omega = \pm \omega$$

$\epsilon$ is invertible under the clifford product, yielding the equation

$$\omega= \pm \epsilon^{-1} \omega \implies \epsilon^{-1} \omega = \pm \omega$$

But $\epsilon^{-1} = -\epsilon$ for Minkowski spacetime, yielding

$$\epsilon^{-1} \omega = \pm \omega \implies -\epsilon \omega = \pm \omega \implies \epsilon \omega = \mp \omega$$

which is a contradiction from what we initially supposed.

In 4d Euclidean space, there is no contradiction, as $\epsilon^{-1} = \epsilon$ there.

Edit: in notation only using Hodge star, this is basically the same result as saying that, in Minkowski spacetime,

$$\star \star \omega = -\omega$$

So if $\star \omega = \pm \omega$, then $\star (\pm \omega) = + \omega$ on the one hand, but also $-\omega$ on the other.

Comment: Right, thank you so much. I didn't notice that in Minkowski spacetime you need to change the sign for the bidual operator (from $(-1)^{k(n-k)}$ to $(-1)^{k(n-k)+1}$).

Comment: Hi Muphrid. I have a question regarding the implications of the lack of anti/self-dual forms on Minkowski spacetime. Is there any chance that I could ask for your opinion in private?

Comment: I'm open to suggestion regarding how to go about that.

Comment: Well, I was thinking about doing it in a chatroom. It's better than nothing, and there's no need for extra privacy :-)

Comment: Fair enough, just let me know where and when.

Comment: Here is the link to the room. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/25114/hodge-self-duality-and-the-behaviour-of-the-electromagnetic-field?tab=general. I'm online right now, if you're not busy.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to the second part of Muphrid answer, let $* \omega=\pm\omega$. Then applying $*$ again
\begin{equation}
*^2\omega=* (\pm\omega) =\omega
\end{equation}
on the other hand on a Lorentzian $n$-manifold $*^2=-(-1)^{p(n-p)}$ where $p$ is the degree of the form on which $*$ is acting. In this case $n=4,p=2$ hence we get $*^2\omega = - \omega$, therefore
\begin{equation}
\omega = -\omega \Rightarrow \omega = 0.
\end{equation}